# pandas MemoryError when read a big dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I'm using pandas to read a big csv file.The file is 14G, and my machine have 60G free memory on Linux.The file about 45,000,000 rows and 55 columns.It seems can't occur this problem.So is any idea to solve it?
The error is

```
packages/pandas/core/internals.py", line 4188, in _stack_arrays
stacked = np.empty(shape, dtype=dtype)
MemoryError
```

Comment: One option is setting the chunksize parameter on pandas.read_csv and process in batches

Comment: I want to random select some rows in this file.When I use chunksize, I'm worried about whether randomness enough.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass argument

```
low_memory=False
```

while reading a csv file.
Or try breaking down into chunks and then appending those chunks.